# Change Root Background color of a Stack Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I upgrade some packages about react-navigation and I have a discrepancy but I cant find out why. When I use modals with cardOverlayEnabled before the upgrade the color behind the stack was white but now is black. Any idea why this happening or how to configure this? I did not change anything in my code, only the packages

[image: now]

[image: before]

packages before:

```js
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
```

packages now

```js
 "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
"react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.25",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.11.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
```

Comment: You must check the migration guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x#stack-navigator

Comment: Offtopic how did you add a banner similar to flutter on react native?? I am talking about that staging tag

Comment: @RajendranNadar I followed this, but this changed does't seem to be mention somewhere.

Comment: banner css: 
position: 'absolute',
    top: 25,
    right: -45,
    width: 170,
    zIndex: 10000,
    transform: [{ rotate: '45deg' }]

Comment: Oh you made a custom element, I thought it is some native stuff to find dev & staging build

Comment: Can you add the snack.expo.io for both previous and new results? I will check